# Why MQ Websphere Queue Manager starts listening trough TCP6

Tags: ibm-mq

As stated in the title. I have queue manager with IPADDR configured as (IPV4). However any time I start listener on that queue manager it listens trough TCP6.

WebSphere Version: 7.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note the documentation on the [Migrating a queue manager to IPv6](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mig.doc/q116940_.htm) page which states that:

> The preferred IP version that two systems use for communicating (if
>   both IPv4 and IPv6 are available) is determined by a new queue manager
>   attribute IPADDRV. **This parameter only has an effect if the hostname
>   resolves ambiguously to both an IPv4 address and an IPv6 address.**

(Emphasis added.)  Note that a parameter whose effect depends on resolving a DNS name would apply mainly to *outbound* connections.

What you want is the `IPADDR` parameter of the [`DEFINE LISTENER`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q085630_.htm) command which states:

> IP address for the listener specified in IPv4 dotted decimal, IPv6
>   hexadecimal notation, or alphanumeric host name form. If you do not
>   specify a value for this parameter, the listener listens on all
>   configured IPv4 and IPv6 stacks.

This is the exception to the `IPADDRV` guidance about name resolution applying to outbound connections.  If you put a DNS name in the `IPADDR` of the listener, then the listener will use whichever IP version address to which that name resolves, or if it resolves to both IPV4 and IPV6 will take the version set in `IPADDRV`.

Since you report `IPADDRV` as having no effect then the listener is either bound to an IPV6 address or DNS name, or else the listener is not bound to any particular address and is listening promiscuously on all interfaces.

Comment: That's what I thought after reading the docs, but when I run `ss -lt` on linux I get following for port 1414:

` LISTEN     0      100            :::1414     :::*`
Wouldn't that indicate it listens only on IPV6 not on all?

Comment: Not necessarily. I saw some addresses in the MQ logs formatted as IPV6 and opened a PMR.  The response from IBM was that some of the system code on which they rely returns IPV4 addresses in mapped IPV6 format on a system that supports both.  To ascertain whether this is a display formatting issue or if it's really listening only on IPV6, try connecting over an IPv4 address from a remote node.  (A remote node because a virtual NIC might translate the connection for you if the socket never leaves the local host.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @T.Rob . I tried connecting from remote host and it works.